# Join table query

Tags: mysql

If I join two tables in a query that looks:

```
SELECT m1.id AS reg, m1.name AS name, f.registered AS status 
FROM phone f 
INNER JOIN members m1 ON m1.id=f.user_id 
WHERE m1.status='1' AND f.registered='1'
```

And then I want to add another 10 user ID's in a array like `m1.id IN (014,01284,014829,075090)` that should also be listed in the result of a query. I want to avoid a third table in the query because I already know users from this table that I need.

The point is that the end result contains all the detail's of users get from the members table by ID's listed in phone table and array.

What the best way to do this?

Comment: you are already selecting m1.id, isn't that what you want?

Comment: @jishi - No, because I get listed only users that are in both lists (in table "phone" and in array). I need those that are in teble "phone" OR in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a bit trivial, so maybe not what you need, but like this?

```
SELECT m1.id AS reg, m1.name AS name, f.registered AS status 
FROM phone f 
INNER JOIN members m1 ON m1.id=f.user_id 
WHERE 
 (m1.status='1' AND f.registered='1')
OR
 (m1.id IN (014,01284,014829,075090) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The INNER JOIN restricts all your results to those with a match in the join table, but that doesn't sound like what you want

I think Nanne's answer will work if you change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT m1.id AS reg, m1.name AS name, f.registered AS status 
FROM phone f 
LEFT JOIN members m1 ON m1.id=f.user_id 
WHERE 
 (m1.status='1' AND f.registered='1')
OR
 (m1.id IN (014,01284,014829,075090) )
```